# Get all class dependencies that are available

Tags: php, reflection, dependencies, autoloader

Sorry if this is a newbie question. I'm just getting used to PHP's Reflection API, and framework-independent namespacing.

I have this code:

```
<?php # Script 3.4 - index.php

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use App\ApptEncoder;
use App\BloggsApptEncoder;
use App\MegaApptEncoder;

$userDefinedClasses = array_filter(
    get_declared_classes(),
    function($className) {
        return call_user_func(
            array(new ReflectionClass($className), 'isUserDefined')
        );
    }

);

echo('<pre>' . var_dump($userDefinedClasses) . '</pre>');
```

Later in the script I do call ApptEncoder, BloggsApptEncoder, and MegaApptEncoder, and they do work. However in this var_dump, they don't show.
All it shows is:

```
/home/vagrant/code/ullman/index.php:20:
array (size=2)
  174 => string 'ComposerAutoloaderInit9447e6ccfd181a47ff4686960bd95f38' (length=54)
  175 => string 'Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader' (length=29)
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure that's how [`get_declared_classes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-classes.php) works:

> Returns an array of the names of the declared classes in the current script.

Current script simply means current file. So as long as you have your classes being included in the same file, they are returned by `get_declared_classes()` otherwise you have to instantiate a new object. For example:

```
// As of PHP 7.0
use App\{ApptEncoder as a, BloggsApptEncoder as b, MegaApptEncoder as c};

$a = new a();
$b = new b();
$c = new c();
```